# How do I show a group variable along with the numeric mid point on the axis of my plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have some data, of which this is a subset:

```
MyDataToSO <- data.frame(Age = c(2, 7, 12, 16, 21),
                     AgeGroup = c("0-4 years", "5-9 years", "10-14 years", "15-17 years", "18-24 years"),
                     Proportion = c(0.963, 0.965, 0.925, 0.701, 0.422))
```

I wish to plot the data so that, on the x-axis, I get the relevant `AgeGroup` showing under the `Age` tick mark. The `Age` values are the mid-points of the `AgeGroup` categories.

I have the plot I want, except for adding in the `AgeGroup` bands under the relevant parts of the x-axis:

```
ggplot(data = MyDataToSO, aes(x = Age, y = Proportion)) +
geom_point() +
geom_point(data = subset(MyDataToSO, Age %in% c(16,21)), color = "green")
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 30, by = 10)) +
labs(x = "Age group", y = "Proportion")
```

The graph works, showing the relevant `Age` in the correct position, but there is no indication that the `Age` values arise from age-groups.

I thought it would be useful to show this by having a second label on the x-axis, so that the resulting x-axis looks a bit like:

```
|
|______________________________...
      |         |         |    ...
      2         7         12   ...
|__________|_________|_________|...
 "0-4 years  5-9 years  10-14 years"...
```

I will need to play around with the font size a bit to get this working. I'd also like to get the age groups lines lighter than the normal printing (e.g. 25% less opaque than normal). I've put the quote marks around the age group labels to stop SO from showing each number there as orange numeric.

How can I add this information onto my graph? I did a search for secondary labels, but only found questions relating to having a secondary axis. As you can see, the required grouping information is stored in `AgeGroup` so I would "just" need to extract the relevant values from there.

Edit: I loaded the `ggh4x` package and the `ggplot` code is now this:

```
ggplot(data = MyDataToSO, aes(interaction(Age, AgeGroup), Proportion)) +
geom_point() +
geom_point(data = subset(MyDataToSO, Age %in% c(16,21)), color = "green")
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 30, by = 10)) +
guides(x = "axis_nested") +
labs(x = "Age group", y = "Proportion")
```

but it is giving an error because the x-axis is continuous.

Edit 2: the green points are interpolations. I now have interpolations for ages 17 through 20. But these repeat the same `AgeGroup` label. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to add annotations, turn off clipping, and put in more space between the axis text and axis titles, like so:

```
ggplot(data = MyDataToSO, aes(x = Age, y = Proportion)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = subset(MyDataToSO, Age %in% c(16,21)), color = "green") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 30, by = 10)) +
  labs(x = "Age group", y = "Proportion") +
  annotate("rect", fill = "gray80",
           xmin = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 18),
           xmax = c(5, 10, 15, 18, 24) - 0.2,
           ymin = 0.28, ymax = 0.32) +
  annotate("text", size = 3,
           x = MyDataToSO$Age + 0.5,
           y = 0.3, label = MyDataToSO$AgeGroup) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.4, 1), clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 25, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)))
```

[image]

Edit: Based on my understanding of additional comment, now splitting out 15:21 individually.

```
MyDataToSO <- data.frame(Age = c(2, 7, 12, 15:21),
                         AgeGroup = c("0-4 years", "5-9 years", "10-14 years", 15:21),
                         Proportion = c(0.963, 0.965, 0.925, 0.701, .740, .677, .610, .540, .470, .401))


ggplot(data = MyDataToSO, aes(x = Age, y = Proportion)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = subset(MyDataToSO, Age %in% c(16,21)), color = "green") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 30, by = 10)) +
  labs(x = "Age group", y = "Proportion") +
  annotate("rect", fill = "gray80",
           xmin = c(0, 5, 10, 15:21) - 0.4,
           xmax = c(5, 10, 15, 16:22) - 0.6,
           ymin = 0.28, ymax = 0.32) +
  annotate("text", size = 3,
           x = MyDataToSO$Age,
           y = 0.3, label = MyDataToSO$AgeGroup) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.4, 1), clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 25, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jon, the green points are interpolations from a larger data set. I have now decided to interpolate multiple ages (15-24). I have a mess on the x-axis labels because groups are now repeated for some ages and not others. Is there an extension of this method to account for some rows having repeated group data? For example, so that ages 16 through 21 now have proportions (.740, .677, .610, .540, .470, .401) - I changed the interpolation method and the 16 and 21 values have changed, but the exact values don't matter here.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want multiple overlapping rows of group annotations, or more detailed interpolations from some years, or something else?

Comment: Ah, I have it. Your explanation still solved it! Under the annotate("text", I set the x-values and y specifically (x = c(2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 16.5, 21.5), y = -0.18, label = c("0-4", "5-9", "10-14", "15-17", "18-24"). I would never have been successful in working all this out without you. :) (My year groups go up to 60-64, so I had to cut the "Years" part out otherwise the text ended up being too small.

Answer (score 2):

The ggh4x package has a function that extends ggplot2 to do this in a more automatic way (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggh4x/vignettes/PositionGuides.html, scroll down to "Nested Relations").

Comment: I can't get continuous x variables to be nested within the discrete categories. I get "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". I've treated the x-axis is continuous, a discrete treatment of the ages would give me incorrect spacing. Could you please expand on your answer, showing how I would apply the package to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way to do this is to create a list or variable where you append the values from `MyDataToSO$Age` and `MyDataToSO$AgeGroup` separated by two carriage returns (i.e. \n). You will pass that list/variable to the 'labels' instruction for scale_x_continuous.

```
library(tidyverse)

MyDataToSO <- tibble(Age = c(2, 7, 12, 16, 21),
                     AgeGroup = c("0-4 years", "5-9 years", "10-14 years", "15-17 years", "18-24 years"),
                     Proportion = c(0.963, 0.965, 0.925, 0.701, 0.422)) %>% 
 mutate(custom_labels = paste0(Age, "\n\n", AgeGroup)) ## This is where you create the custom labels

ggplot(data = MyDataToSO, aes(x = Age, y = Proportion)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_point(data = subset(MyDataToSO, Age %in% c(16,21)), color = "green") + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 30, by = 10)) +
    labs(x = "Age group", y = "Proportion") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(MyDataToSO$Age), ## Here you pass the relevant ages. Should be aligned with the custom_labels
                       labels = c(MyDataToSO$custom_labels)) ## Here you pass the custom label balues
```

[image]